# c# Pass Socket Connection

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a List of sockets `List<Socket> Clients;`

`Client[index]` is receiving Data in a UI Form works perfectly , but i want to pass that socket to another Form2 so :

```
    public Form2(Socket Client)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this._Client = Client;
    }
```

in my Form1:

```
 Form2 f2 = new Form2(this.Clients[0]);
 f2.Show();
```

My issue is i don't receive from the New socket i still receive from socket on Form1 !
i m confused how can i receive from the new socket !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should only be one that will receive data from the socket. You should pass the data instead of the socket.

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    public void HandleData(byte[] data)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer sir but what if the data is not stopping for example data keeps being sent how can i handle all the data sent while the form2 is running ?

Comment: Tcp is a stream. So, some sort of protocol should be used. This protocol defines a packet. Instead of passing a byte array, you could pass a class that represents a packet. This will make the `HandlePacket ()` will be called each time the form1 has a complete packet.

Comment: Yes Sir i already watched some tutorials about it ! , thanks sir!